# Adding Excel Textbox at the end of data in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am using this code to enter a simple Text box in excel sheet

Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizon‌​tal, 60, 1, 1, 60).Select

But I want its position to be automatically at the end of data of excel sheet. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 60, 1, 1, 60).Select I am using this code to enter a simple Text box in excel sheet

Comment: Looks to me like you can already add a textbox then.  You might want to edit your question to include that code and clarify your actual question.